# Disable an addEventListener function when needed

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

This function is needed for some time. But when tasks are completed I need to disable it, that after clicking on 'board' it wouldn't work.

```js
board.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('circle')) {
        score++
        event.target.remove()
        createRandomCircle()
    } else if (!event.target.classList.contains('circle')) {
        fault++
    }
})

//Here I want to deactivate this event listener
```

Comment: To remove an event listener, you need a reference to the event handler function. 1. Create a function (give it an appropriate name). 2. Pass this function name to `addEventListener`. 3. To remove the event listener, pass the same function name to `removeEventListener`

Comment: You will need an instance of the callback function. you can then use `.removeEventListener(name, fn)`.

Comment: Thanks. Two first answers were correct. I was expecting, that I can disable function without transforming it to board.addEventListener('click', function)

Comment: @Yousaf The fact you need a reference to the exact function is bizarre to me. I really think it should work similarly to `setTimeout`. You receive a *listenerId* of sorts and you'd remove it with that ID. That would make more sense to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call a handler function that returns a new named function ([a closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)) to act as the listener. You can then go through your tasks, and remove the listener when they're complete.

```js
const board = document.querySelector('#board');

board.addEventListener('click', handler(), false);

function handler() {

  // This is the function the listener uses
  return function listener(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
    console.log('Task one');
    console.log('Task two');
    board.removeEventListener('click', listener);
    console.log('The button no longer works.');
  }

}
```

```html
<button id="board">Board</button>
```